# Regex | PowerShell: How do I split a string at the underscores?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to get the following information between the '_' and make it work with the code below.  I'm not sure how to update the $Results variable correctly.  The code is a snippet of working code, it just needs to be modified to work with the new sample data.

How can this code be modified to work with the sample data to get the desired result, please?  Thanks for your help.

**SAMPLE DATA:**

- 123456_FileName1_01012021.pdf
- 123457_FileName2_01012021.pdf
- 123458_FileName3_01012021.pdf
- 123459_FileName4_01012021.pdf
- 123460_FileName5_01012021.pdf

**DESIRED RESULT:**

[image]

**POWERSHELL CODE:**

```
    #Get the names of the files
    $destinationPath = '\path1\test.csv'
    $InStuff = @(Get-ChildItem "\path2\"-Name -Recurse) 
    
    #---Remove  if exists
    if (Test-Path $destinationPath) {
      Remove-Item $destinationPath
    }
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    #
$results = switch -Regex ($InStuff) {
    '[^-]*' { 
        $CodeID,$FileName = $matches.2 -split '_'
        [pscustomobject]@{            
            CodeID  = $CodeID
            FileName = $Filename            
            DateCode  = $matches.3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your filenames show underscores `_`, but you're splitting on a hyphen `-` Please show us better examples, because now they do not match the code and the outputted PsCustomObject

Comment: Great catch @Theo!  I've updated the code to better reflect what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $InStuff is an array with filenames like that, why not simply do:

```
$InStuff = '123456_FileName1_01012021.pdf','123457_FileName2_01012021.pdf',
           '123458_FileName3_01012021.pdf','123459_FileName4_01012021.pdf',
           '123460_FileName5_01012021.pdf'

$InStuff | ForEach-Object {
    $id, $fileName, $date = $_ -split '_'
    [PsCustomObject]@{'ID:' = $id; 'FileName' = $fileName; 'Date' = $date}
}
```

Output:

```
ID:    FileName  Date        
---    --------  ----        
123456 FileName1 01012021.pdf
123457 FileName2 01012021.pdf
123458 FileName3 01012021.pdf
123459 FileName4 01012021.pdf
123460 FileName5 01012021.pdf
```

You may also want to strip the extension off with something like

```
$id,$fileName,$date = ($_ -split '\.')[0] -split '_'
```

or

```
$id,$fileName,$date = $_ -replace '\.[a-z]+$' -split '_'
```

to get this result

```
ID:    FileName  Date    
---    --------  ----    
123456 FileName1 01012021
123457 FileName2 01012021
123458 FileName3 01012021
123459 FileName4 01012021
123460 FileName5 01012021
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks, @Theo!